# WPF: How to get value of ListView element on which i called context menu?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I have listview in "gridview style" with 2 columns. I wonder how to get first column value of item on which i called context menu (CM has one button only where i want to handle value)?

Here is XAML:

```
        <ListView.Resources>
            <ContextMenu x:Key="ContextMenu">
                <MenuItem Header="Run test with parameters" x:Name="runTestWithParams" Click="runTestWithParams_Click" />
            </ContextMenu>
        </ListView.Resources>
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource ContextMenu}"/>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

And here is contextMenu button handeler:

```
    private void runTestWithParams_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string valueOfFirstColumn = // something like ItemThatWasClicked["ID"].ToString();     
    }
```

If you have any ideas please help me.

**SOLUTION FOUND**

It was necessary to create handler of RightMouseUp event and get value I need from its sender,
because of Context_Menu_button_Click's sender does not contain info about item it was clicked on, but contains info about ContextMenu.
So... I handled it like this:

Handler:

```
    private void HandleMouseRightButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        ListViewItem selected = sender as ListViewItem;
        String valueINeed = (selected.Content as TestIdentification).Id;
    }
```

XAML:

```
<Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <EventSetter Event="MouseRightButtonUp" Handler="HandleMouseRightButtonUp" />
</Style>
```

Thanks for all!

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to handle the [ContextMenuOpening event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613568.aspx) on the ListView. From there, you can access the [ContextMenuEventArgs.OriginalSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.routedeventargs.originalsource.aspx) property in order to get the element from which the event originates.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is a common one... the `ContextMenu` is not part of the main visual tree that the rest of your controls are in and so it does not have the correct `DataContext` by default. However, you'll be glad to hear that it is relatively simple to fix this. I generally use the `Tag` property to pass the `DataContext` to the `ContextMenu`:

```
<ListView.Resources>
    <ContextMenu x:Key="ContextMenu" DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag, 
        RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
        <MenuItem Header="Run test with parameters" x:Name="runTestWithParams" 
            Click="runTestWithParams_Click" />
    </ContextMenu>
</ListView.Resources>
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type YourNamespace:YourDataType}">
        <Grid Tag="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" 
            ContextMenu="{StaticResource ContextMenu}">
            <!--Define what your data objects look like here or just use this-->
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Now, I've not done this quite in this way before, so we *might* have some problems to work through, but give this a go anyway. When the user clicks on the `MenuItem`, you should now have access to the data object using the `sender.DataContext` property. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: U said that u use Tag property.. Is it property u created?

Comment: No, practically all controls have a `Tag` property which is free for us to use in any way we see fit.